# How to filter a string against the characters from a variable?

Tags: bash, variable, string

I am trying to remove special characters (by passing them as a variable) from a string variable below command able to remove single characters not multiple?

```
string=#@$AAA%* 
a=#$@%*                  # Special characters which have to remove from variable
b=`echo $string|sed 's/\${a}//g'`
echo $b
```

Comment: please also keep in mind to quote your variable that you should. read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/72456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your commands.

- `string=#@$AAA%*` and `a=#$@%*`: here the `$AAA` and `$@` parts are interpreted as variables. You should single-quote the strings so that they are interpreted literally.
- For the `sed` part, you are asking it to replace a literal string of `#$@%*` *in order* with nothing. If you want separate characters, you'd need to use a different format, e.g. the character class `[#$@%*]`. However, in this case, I'd just use `tr -d` instead, which is much simpler.
- Also, `$(…)` is preferred over backticks.
- I'd also use a here-string (`<<<`) instead of an echo, just to save a few cycles.
- I noticed that Kusalananda edited my answer to add `"` quotes around variables. I deliberated over this too, but figured I wouldn't because it would be simpler, and not necessary for your specific question. However, I agree that this is the "right" way to do things. I've added `"` quotes around the other variables and the `$(…)` construct; in this case they are unnecessary, but also good practice.

Hence the final commands are

```
string='#@$AAA%*'
a='#$@%*'
b="$(<<<"$string" tr -d "$a")"
echo "$b"
```

Comment: You should've left it at @Kusalananda's edit. The extra quotes *you* added are absolutely useless -- unlike those around `"$a"` and `"$b"`, they make no difference, no matter the value of `string` and `a`. Example: `s='/b  *  .? *  * b/'; a='/*'; b=$(<<<$s tr -d "$a"); echo "$b"`

Comment: @mosvy Yes, good point… I guess my thinking was that Kusalananda's were also not necessary in this case either. Admittedly `$b` may well contain whitespace in another variant, but `$a` almost certainly would not (at least not in a way that would break). I agree that my quotes are even more useless, but I figured I'd use them for "good practice", in a general sense… which was likely Kusalananda's thinking? I've edited the question to point this out anyway.

Comment: the quotes around `"$a"` and `"$b"` are not just "good practice" (ie cargo cult). Try my example without either of them and you will see that they really make a difference.

Comment: @mosvy Ah yes okay. I forgot to use bash instead of my normal zsh. Yes, the `*` causes problems. Hopefully my edit includes this interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

No need to run external commands when using recent shells' "parameter expansion":

```
echo ${string//["$a"]}
AAA
```